# Centering site content without overlapping header & footer

Tags: html, css

I have a basic site structure with a header, a footer and a content area.
Almost all of the solutions I could find to center the content of the page uses CSS absolute positioning, with setting the margins of the content div, and having it float in the center of the browser window.
However, this results in the content covering the header and/or the footer when the window's size is reduced.
Instead, I would like the page to scroll when it cannot fit into the window.

Here is a screenshot of the page:
[image: layout -- area with red border should be vertically centered]

The area with the red border should be vertically centered without covering any of the other elements.

Here is the HTML&CSS I'm using:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Layout Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">Header Content</div>
        <div class="articleContainer">
            <div class="articleLeft">
                <div class="articleTitle">
                    <h1 class="articleTitle">Title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="articleText">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="articleRight">
                <div class="articleImage"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="stepper">Stepper</div>
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@charset "UTF-8";


* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -48px;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #7FF152;
    height: 48px;
}

.articleContainer {
    background-color: #CCFFFF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 700px;
    clear: both;
    min-height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    border: medium solid #FF0000;
}

.articleLeft {
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
    width: 330px;
}

.articleTitle {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

.articleText {
    max-height: 350px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.articleRight {
    float: right;
    height: 450px;
    width: 330px;
    background: url(articleImage.fw.png) no-repeat center center;
}

.stepper {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #CC6633;
    text-align: center;
    height: 48px;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 48px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

I have uploaded both to here: http://cl.ly/3f2o1v0U2c0k

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gudmN/1/

Thank you for the help.

Comment: In such questions I recommend to show two screen shots, one of the situation you want and another for the situation you don't want. I got confused.

Comment: little present to you http://jsfiddle.net/gudmN/1/ i think is better than downloading - unzipping, get run you code

Comment: can you post your desired result image what exactly you are looking........

Comment: Is not clear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

1) add `margin: 0 auto; height: auto; float: left` to `.articlecontainer`.
2) Make the header and footer `float: left; width: 100%; height: 48px`